# Vuetify 2 v-navigation-drawer not showing again after dialog = false

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, navigation-drawer

I'm using the navigation drawer to show my data list in a dialog box.it works and shows fine when I first open it,but when I open the dialog again, the whole navigation drawer disappears. there's also no problem with my data GET.

```
 <v-navigation-drawer floating height="140px" class="w-100">
            <v-list dense rounded>
              <v-divider></v-divider>
              <v-list-item-group class="mt-3" color="primary" mandatory>
                <v-list-item v-for="(desc, index) in dataList" :key="index" @click="getDesc(desc)">
                  <v-list-item-action-text class="pe-4">{{ desc.title }}</v-list-item-action-text>
                  <v-list-item-content>

                  </v-list-item-content>
                  <v-list-item-icon>
                    <v-icon small color="red" class="pe-2" @click="deleteDesc(desc.eid)">mdi-delete</v-icon>
                  </v-list-item-icon>
                </v-list-item>
                <v-list-item v-if="!dataList.length">
                  مرحله ای وجود ندارد
                </v-list-item>
              </v-list-item-group>
            </v-list>
          </v-navigation-drawer>
```

it's inside a form.
my data get func in the dialog component:

```
async getData() {
  await this.$store.dispatch("axiosGet",
      {url: 'folder/api/descriptions', params: {Title: this.title}}).then(response => {
    if (response.status === 'error') return
    this.dataList = response.data.data.data
  })
},
```

Comment: `getDesc` click event might be culprit here. Can you please help me in understanding what this `getDesc` method doing ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `v-model` to the `v-navigation-drawer` in order to show and hide it. Here is a minimum required example for you to go.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      drawer: false
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@6.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-navigation-drawer v-model="drawer" floating height="140px" class="w-100">
      <v-list dense rounded>
        <v-divider></v-divider>
        <v-list-item-group class="mt-3" color="primary" mandatory>
          <v-list-item>
            <v-list-item-action-text class="pe-4">idk</v-list-item-action-text>
          </v-list-item>
        </v-list-item-group>
      </v-list>
    </v-navigation-drawer>
    <v-btn absolute @click="drawer = !drawer">Toggle</v-btn>
  </v-app>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this answer is not to late.

You need to "reset" the dialog by using `v-if="yourDialogModel"' on the outmost element inside the dialog.

So in my case it looks something like this:

```js
 <v-dialog
    v-model="dialogHistory"
    fullscreen
    :scrim="false">
     <v-card v-if="dialogHistory">
        <!-- your nav-drawer, toolbar, content, etc here -->
     </v-card>
 </v-dialog>
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow !
Thanks for sharing an answer.
Do you think the important part is the `v-if` and not the `v-model`?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).